# How do I stop the scriptaculous blind-down effect from flickering when element has padding?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, scriptaculous, effects

it seems that when the blind down effect is used on an element with padding it looks a bit awkward. It seems to blind down too far and then jumps back. It's a very subtle thing but is really annoying.

I don't have an online example but if you go to the demo on github and give the element a padding-top or bottom with firebug or something you'll see what I mean.

http://github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/wiki/effect-blinddown

http://madrobby.github.io/scriptaculous/effect-blinddown/

Anybody found a way to stop it?

Comment: After a bit of experimentation I've discovered this isn't such a big deal because you can give the element within the blinding down element a margin. Looks about the same and it works without this jittering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not resolved this but as I said in my comment, this issue can be worked around pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

In the off chance someone runs across this trying to solve this problem, you can put your content inside a div inside the BlindDown() div.

That is,

```
<div id="blindthis" style="display:none;">
     <div style="padding:10px;">content goes here</div>
</div>

<script>
     new Effect.BlindDown('blindthis')
</script>
```